# How does the dot means in sql when the where clause is different

Tags: sql

i express me
i saw recently this piece of code

```
SELECT a.id a.name FROM department
```

the issue is that 'departement' is a table name.

and 'a' is also a table name which contains id and name fileds.

why we use 2 differnt table name ? it is not the same thing... it's difficult to get brain for me, so explain me.

lower in the code there is a left join, maybe it can have a rapport ?

Comment: This particularly query doesn't appear to be valid, as `a` is not a table in the query.  So it's not really clear what you're asking.  If you're asking "how does this work" the answer is "it doesn't".

Comment: Your query won't even run.  This is probably what it should be: `SELECT a.id, a.name FROM department a` ... my advice to you is to spend time with a good SQL tutorial; this isn't a good way to learn SQL.

Comment: Yes, but lower there is a left join. May it be a rapport in this case ?

Comment: @J.Doe: *"but lower there is a left join"* - No there isn't.  At least not in the code you're showing us.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `a` in this case is called a table _alias_. It would be a good idea to do some googling on that. In future just keep in mind that you need to post all of the query, not just a bit of it. It can be very impractical and time consuming to draw the entire picture out through comments. Best of luck

Comment: no, there is no alias but a left join. but i did not showed all the code

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, "a" is a table alias. It doesn't appear that "a" is the alias for the table: "departments". Aliases are assigned in the FROM statements and JOIN statements. If you can show us all of the code, we can tell you exactly what "a" represents.

In the meantime, I would suggest giving this a read: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 0):

No. It wasn't an alias. it was a foreign key in the table department. You lied.